# Invalid Range.startOffset of the selected text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, dom-events

I want to select the text using the mouse and then store the start and end position of the text, and also highlight the selected text. Issue is, from the second selection onwards the startOffset value is not correct. Its starts from the end of the previous range

```js
$(function () {

    let result = [];
    let counter = 1;

    $("#btnCopy").click(function () {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText("");
        if (window.getSelection()) {
            let sel = window.getSelection();
            let range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            let selectedText = range.toString();
            let startOffset = range.startOffset;
            let endOffset = startOffset + selectedText.length;

            let obj = {
                id: counter,
                start: startOffset,
                end: endOffset,
                text: selectedText
            }
            counter++;

            result.push(obj);

            document.designMode = "on";
            
            // Colorize text
            document.execCommand("BackColor", false, "red");

            // Set design mode to off
            document.designMode = "off";

            $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(result));
            //navigator.clipboard.writeText(JSON.stringify(result));
        }
    })       
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> To Reproduce the issue. Select Text below using mouse -> then click on copy button. Notice the that from the second selection onward the start value is not correct. It starts from the end of previous selection instead of from the begining of the text</p>

<div id="result">
    
</div>
<p></p>
<div id="ocrText">Machine learning (ML) is a field of inquiry devoted to understanding and building methods that 'learn', that is, methods that leverage data to improve performance on some set of tasks.[1] It is seen as a part of artificial intelligence. Machine learning algorithms build a model based on sample data, known as training data, in order to make predictions or decisions without being explicitly programmed to do so.[2] Machine learning algorithms are used in a wide variety of applications, such as in medicine, email filtering, speech recognition, and computer vision, where it is difficult or unfeasible to develop conventional algorithms to perform the needed tasks.[3]</div>

<div>
    <button id="btnCopy" type="button" class="btn-primary">Copy</button>    
</div>
```

Comment: Your second "selection" is not selecting the same *element* as the first selection - because you've split the div #ocrText into 3 elements.   Select some text, then inspect element - how do you think the background colour is being applied?  It's adding a `<span>`.   You'll need to iterate all of #ocrText's nodes (not jquery.children as that doesn't include text nodes) to determine your start position within #ocrText

Comment: But it is possible that the selected text could be present in other nodes as well.

Comment: Oh, it undoubtedly is.   But  `range.startOffset` is given you the offset from the start element, not the start element's parent.